# OpenCV detecting a face, cropping a profile, programmatically marking and removing background with grabCut

Tags: python, opencv

Given a [random picture](https://www.pexels.com/photo/men-s-blue-dress-shirt-1043471/), I'm successfully detecting a face and cropping out the calculated ROI.  Next thing I'm trying to achieve is to remove the background, where I'm currently stuck.

I'm trying to manipulate [grabcut.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/grabcut.py) to mark the background and foreground programmatically to get better results using `grabCut()` with `GC_WITH_INIT_MASK`

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('./man.jpeg', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

profile = cv.CascadeClassifier('/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.1.0_2/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

faces = profile.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

print(len(faces))

if len(faces) > 1 or len(faces) == 0:
  print('more than one or zero found')
  exit()

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
  y1 = int(y - h/2)
  y2 = int(y + h*2)
  x1 = int(x - w/2)
  x2 = int(x + w*2)
  //TODO: check if dimensions outside original img
  cropped = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]

//estimate marking sections which are BG and FG
cv.line(cropped, (int(cropped.shape[0]/6), 0), (int(cropped.shape[0]/6), int(cropped.shape[1]/3)), (0), 5)
cv.line(cropped, (int(cropped.shape[0]), 0), (int(cropped.shape[0] - cropped.shape[0]/4), int(cropped.shape[1]/3)), (0), 5)
cv.line(cropped, (int(cropped.shape[0]/6), int(cropped.shape[1] - cropped.shape[1]/6)), (int(cropped.shape[0] - cropped.shape[0]/6*2), int(cropped.shape[1] - cropped.shape[1]/6)), (255), 5)

mask = np.zeros(cropped.shape[:2], np.uint8)

bgModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64) 
fgModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)

//getting an error of incorrect indicies?
#mask[cropped == 0] = 0
#mask[cropped == 255] = 1

cv.grabCut(cropped, mask, None, bgModel, fgModel, 5, cv.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)

//tried both...second from grabcut.py
#mask2 = np.where((mask==2) | (mask==0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
mask2 = np.where((mask==1) + (mask==3), 255, 0).astype('uint8')

output = cv.bitwise_and(cropped, cropped, mask=mask2)

cv.imshow('img', output)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Right now I'm getting 
`error: (-215:Assertion failed) !bgdSamples.empty() && !fgdSamples.empty() in function 'initGMMs'`

This is basically a collection of many different tutorials, trial and errors.  I am using this as a learning experience so any guidance will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(cropped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask[gray == 0] = 0
mask[gray == 255] = 1
```

I think maybe the mask should not be empty in the mode of `cv.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK`

Comment: I `cv.imgshow('img', cropped)` and the image is displayed...as I said, I'm still learning.  Does everything else seem like it should be working?  What does it mean that bgmodel and fgmodel cannot be empty?  Everywhere I've seen they are initialized with `np.zeros` so all zeros.

Comment: When I uncomment those, I get an error of `mask[cropped == 0] = 0 IndexError: too many indices for array`.  `print(cropped)` results in (665, 665, 3) and `print(mask)` results in (665, 665).  cropped.ndim  = 3 and mask.ndim = 2.  Is that the issue?  If so, what's the fix?

Comment: This should fix for cropped is rgb image which has three dimensions. You can see this webpage for more details: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html

Comment: That part was fixed, now the error is `(-215:Assertion failed) N >= K in function 'kmeans'`.  Found this as potential fix? https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/kmeans.cpp

Comment: I would suggest you use debug mode to see how this graph-cut algorithm choose k(also do not look at github for it is in the master branch not your local version of opencv). This message means the k cluster will not be generated because your sample size is smaller than k

Comment: The link you showed is what I was initially using. Trying to figure out this kmeans error now and how to fix it...